# Помогите поправить исправить ошибки в программе C#

Tags: c#

[image: задание]

Помогите пожалуйста поправить программу, не понимаю где ошибка. Задание прилагаю

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double x = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text),
               y = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text),
               c = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        double d, d1, d2, d3, Min, Max, m = Math.E, n = Math.Pow(Math.E, -x);
        if (n >= y)
            if (x > 0)
            {
                d = Math.Pow(x, 3);
                d1 = Math.Pow(m, -x + 1);
                d2 = (x + y);
                d3 = Math.Log(10);
                if (d2 > d3) Max = d2;
                else Max = d3;
                if (d1 < d) Min = d1;
                else Min = d;
                if (Max < Min) d = Max;
                else d = Min;
            }
            else
                if (n >= y)
                    if (x <= 0)
                        d = 1 - Math.Pow(x, 2);
                    else
                    {
                        d = Math.Pow(c, 2) * x;
                        d1 = d * Math.Cos(x + y);
                        if (d > d1) Max = d;
                        else Max = d1;
                        d = Max;
                        }
                        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(d);
                        }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Поставьте точку останова на строку `if (n >= y)` и дальше по-шагам идите и проверяйте значения переменных, так вы самостоятельно найдете где ошибка.

Comment: Если бы я могла сама найти ошибку, этого вопроса бы здесь не было и такие умники бы мне не отвечали.

Comment: что хоть за ошибка: в вычислениях или в синтаксисе?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал так:

```
double c = 0.1;
double x = 0.2;
double y = 0.3;

double d;

if (Math.Pow(Math.E, -x) >= y)
{
    if (x > 0)
    {
        d = new double[] { x * x * x, new double[] { Math.Log10(x), x + y }.Max() }.Min();
    }
    else
    {
        d = 1 - x * x;
    }
}
else
{
    d = new double[] { c * c * x,  Math.Cos(x + y)}.Max();
}
```

Только не понимаю как вычислить `dcos(x + y)`, если `d` неизвестно.